# Doctrine Repository accept array for getAll

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a repository, I need a custom getALL query which checks for items based on an array of data. e.g. I need to be able to send $params = [ 'type' => [ 'type1', 'type2' ], 'username' => $username ] but I can currently only send one parameter such as: $params = ['type' => 'type1', 'username' => $username].

What would be the best way of adding acceptance of an array (like the one above) to this getAll query?:

```
public function getAllQuery($params = [])
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    if(count($params))
    {
        foreach($params as $param => $value)
        {
            //todo need to make it accept an array of parameters
            if(in_array($param, $this->getClassMetadata()->getFieldNames()) && $param != 'deleted')
            {
                $query
                    ->andWhere(sprintf('c.%1$s LIKE :%1$s', $param))
                    ->setParameter($param, sprintf('%%%s%%', $value));
            }

            /*code already exists here for checking other parameters 
              outside of 'type' (e.g. 'username') */



        }


    }

    return $query->getQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment so I will answer without to be sur that I've understand the question. Are you waiting something like this ? In this case it's more a PHP problem than Doctrine.

The results of the past code : [here](https://eval.in/108739).

```
$params = array( 'type' => array( 'type1', 'type2' ), 'username' => 'flavien');
$requiredFields = array('type');

if(count($params))
{
    foreach($params as $param => $value)
    {
        if(in_array($param, $requiredFields) && $param != 'deleted')
        {
              if(is_array($value))
              {
                    echo "My param: {$param}" . PHP_EOL;
                    for($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
                          echo  $value[$i] . PHP_EOL;
                    }
              }
        }
    }
}
```